# Crontab vs Visitor powered php to send reminder mail

Tags: php, cron

I want to send reminder mails from my website, hosted were I live (sweden).

Which is more "good-practise" and/or reliable: Crontab or a php code sent when a user visits the website and (without him/her needing to know) run the php code that sends the mail?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sending reminder mails to yourself?
Or are you mailing inactive users or similar?

A cronjob could do the trick.
You could set a script to run every week to check for user inactivity, or every 5 minutes if you're sending yourself reminders via email.

User fired scripts would not be a good option for an automated process.

Comment: ^ Cronjobs are your safest bet. Leave the user out of it :)